# How to print my matrix in a tester class?

Tags: arrays, printing

so i wrote a program that multiplies two matrices and it works fine. I'm just having a problem printing the right answer in the right way in my tester class, here are my two classes:

```
    public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int a[ ][ ]= new int[][]{ {1,2,-2,0} , {-3,4,7,2} , {6,0,3,1} };
    int b[ ][ ]= new int[][]{ {-1,3} , {0,9} , {1,-11} , {4,-5} };
    MatrixMult.mult(a,b);
    System.out.println((MatrixMult.mult(a,b)));

}
}
```

and the other:

```
     import java.util.*;
     public class MatrixMult {
         public static int[][] mult(int a[][], int b[][]){
            int[][] matrix= new int[3][2];
            int i,j,k;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
        for( j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++){
            for (k = 0 ; k < 4 ; k++){
                matrix[i][j] += (a[i][k]*b[k][j]);

                    }
            //System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "\t");
        }
    }
    return matrix;          
}
     }
```

When i print, i get this:

```
    [[I@1948cc8c
```

What i need to get, is this:

```
    -3      43
    18      -60
    1       -20
```

Answer (score 0):

`MatrixMult.mult()` returns an `int[][]`.  This is what you are printing.

There are two approaches to take to this.  One is to keep the `int[][]` as the format you are working with and then print that.

Changing the Tester class to handle this:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[ ][ ]= new int[][]{ {1,2,-2,0} , {-3,4,7,2} , {6,0,3,1} };
        int b[ ][ ]= new int[][]{ {-1,3} , {0,9} , {1,-11} , {4,-5} };
        int[][] result = MatrixMult.mult(a,b);
        for(int[] i : result) {
            for(int j : i) {
                System.out.print(j);
                System.out.print('\t');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

In here we iterate over the result which gives us int arrays, and then we iterate over the ints in those int arrays, printing a new line after each row.

The other approach is to make a Matrix class that contains a `toString()` method (and probably a `mult` method too).

You would then have code that looks like:

```
public class Matrix {
    private int[][] data;
    public Matrix(int [][] arg) {
        data = new int[arg.length][arg[0].length];
        for(int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < arg[0].length; j++) {
                data[i][j] = arg[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public Matrix mult(Matrix arg) {
        int[][] result;

        /* arbtirary sized matrix multiplication code here */

        return new Matrix(result);
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for(int[] i : data) {
            for(int j : i) {
                result.append(j)
                      .append('\t');
            }
            result.append('\n');
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

In this approach you are writing a constructor that then copies the array passed in into its own internal data structure and has a toString that looks remarkably similar to the code that loops over and prints out the raw int[][] structure.

This then builds a StringBuilder and takes the String from this.  Then code that does:

```
Matrix foo;
/* stuff */
System.out.println(foo);
```

will work properly because the call to print it will ask for the string representation of the object, and that is defined.